# How to check if an object member exists in array by property?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, properties

Can't get my head around how to check if an object member exists in array by property.

I have the following object:

```
PS> $siteUser

Id Title                            LoginName                                                                   Email
-- -----                            ---------                                                                   -----
1305 cinuwyl@banit.club             i:0#.f|membership|urn%3aspo%3aguest#cinuwyl@banit.club                      cinuwyl@banit.club
```

I would like to check if the string `membership` from the property `LoginName` exists within the array:

```
federateddirectoryclaimprovider
tenant
membership
```

I've gotten only as far as getting a match by specifying the array index for `membership`:

```
$siteUsers.LoginName | Where-Object {$_ -match $inclusionObjects[2]}
```

However, this requires that I know the array index for the matching string in advance.

Another thing I've tried but that yields no results is:

```
$siteUsers | Where-Object {$inclusionObjects | ForEach-Object {$_ -match $_.LoginName}}
```

Is there a way to kind of go through each item in the array?

Comment: so I understand You need to find if rows that have phrase "Membership" in Login Column  exist in array? if so - I'd think it's just `($siteusers |Where-Object {$_.LoginName -like "*Membership*"}).count `

Comment: Almost. I would not only like to check for 'membership' but any item in the array. I have worded it wrong in my initial post, sorry. So for example the LoginName might contain 'tenant' instead of membership and the real-world objects contains more than one member. This should also be a match.

Answer (score 0):

To check if ANY word in list matches the `$siteUsers.LoginName`, you can use following:

```
$siteUsers = [pscustomobject]@{
  Id=1305;
  Title='cinuwyl@banit.club';
  LoginName='i:0#.f|membership|urn%3aspo%3aguest#cinuwyl@banit.club';
  Email='cinuwyl@banit.club'
}

$inclusionObjects = [string[]]'federateddirectoryclaimprovider','tenant','membership'
$predicate = [Func[string,bool]]{$siteUsers.LoginName.Contains($args[0])}

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Any($inclusionObjects, $predicate)
```

Comment: Thanks, trying to understand this code. Would this require that each object would have to be cast to a pscustomobject? My initial example only states one member in the object, however, the real world object is the output of a cmdlet and has several members.

Comment: No, this is just demo data. It can be any object.

Comment: Thanks. If I run your exact code I'm getting:
`Cannot find an overload for "Any" and the argument count: "2"`
Had to translate a little bit from German.

Comment: Please add converion before `$inclusionObjects`: `[string[]]$inclusionObjects`. Make sure `$predicate` is of type `[Func[string,bool]]`.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work but as soon as $siteUsers contains more than one member I only get one evaluation that is $False. Is it possible to implement a loop that loops through each member of $siteUsers?